# luksOpen: No key available with this passphrase

Tags: password, luks

I've created a **encrypted volume with LUKS** at home and was looking to use it at work too. Unfortunately, that's not possible. Whyever, I'm unable to access the encrypted data on *any* other computer than my workstation at home.

After entering the passphrase, I do recieve this error message:

[image: Gnome screenshot]

```
No key available with this passphrase.
```

Strangely enough, I've *no WTF complications* to access the encrypted data on my home workstation. How can I encrypt the volume ?

Comment: Please post the content of `/etc/crypttab` from both systems.

Comment: The content of `/etc/crypttab` is empty on my computer at work. What does it mean?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

LUKS sometimes gives the `No key available` error message when the cipher isn't supported. Which cipher did you use? For supported ciphers, check `/proc/crypto`.

Also, passphrase may depend on keyboard layout and (if it has non-ascii characters) charset encoding. The keyboard layout problem can be worked around by adding another passphrase that would match the same keysequence typed in the other layout. So for example if you have one box with a QWERTZ keyboard and another with QWERTY, you could just switch Z and Y for the second passphrase.

Also check `dmesg` if there are any kernel messages related to opening the encrypted container, it may point you to other errors.

If you're looking for a simpler solution and don't mind redoing it from scratch, how about encrypting the disk at your work computer and then see if you can open that at home.

Answer (score 2):

Your caps lock might be secretly on (no indicator light) when you enter the passphrase. Tap that once and re-enter password

Comment: +1 I had the same message when I was simply using the wrong password.